# Ruby returns TypeError: can't convert Object into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm starting to work with Ruby and I have the following module:

```
module RadioreportHelper
  @totalsum = 0
  @radio
  @daysAndTotals

  def load(service, transactionsPerDay)
    puts "#{service} : #{transactionsPerDay}"
    @radio = service
    @daysAndTotals = transactionsPerDay

    transactionsPerDay.each{|day, total|
      @totalsum += total
    }
  end
  attr_reader :radio, :daysAndTotals, :totalsum
end
```

I'm running the following unit test case:

```
class RadioreportHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  fixtures :services
  def test_should_return_populated_radio_module
    service = Service.find_by_name("Mix")
    transactionsPerDay = {1=>20, 2=>30, 4=>40, 5=>50}
    radioReport = RadioreportHelper.load(service, transactionsPerDay)
    assert_not_nil(radioReport)
    assert_equal("Mix", radioReport.radio.name)
  end
end
```

But I always get the following error:
TypeError: can't convert Service into String

I want the **service** object to be in the module RadioreportHelper and stored it in the *@radio* variable not the string.
Thanks, for the all the help guys!

Comment: Does Service.find_by_name("Mix").to_string also throw the error?
If so, consider converting it yourself instead of relying on its to_string method.

Comment: No, that one works just fine. Service.find_by_name("Mix") bring a "service" object from the service fixture with no problem. I want the service object to pass to the RadioreportHelper module.  However, when I pass it from my test to the module, it says that error (TypeError: can't covert Service into String).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `to_s` method to your Service model.

```
def to_s
  service # or some other method in the model that returns a string
end
```

It is not necessary to call `to_s` from inside an interpolated expression, i.e. `"#{service}"` will return the result of `service.to_s`.

**EDIT**

Never mind all of this. Your `RadioreportHelper.load` method is not being reached -- instead you are getting `load` from ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable. Try renaming the `load` method to something else.

(I hate name collisions.)

Comment: Hey zetetic! I already have that to_s implemented in the service. But I wanted to save the "service" into the RadioreportHelper and hold the reference in the @radio variable so I can use it in the views. I'm not really understanding the error (TypeError: can't convert Service into String). It should keep the "service" that is coming from test to the module, correct?

Comment: Strange. Does the error only occur when testing? Or does it also occur when rendering the template?

Comment: I've only tried it when testing. I'm using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3

Comment: I changed the method from "load" to "loadRadioTransaction" and now I have this: NoMethodError: undefined method `loadRadioTransaction' for RadioreportHelper:Module

Comment: The test class isn't finding the module definition. Maybe a name or path issue? Try adding `include RadioreportHelper` in the test file.

Comment: THAT'S IT! I just added include RadioreportHelper and it worked! Thx zetetic!

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely try this:

```
puts "#{service.to_s} : #{transactionsPerDay}"
```

Although I am not sure how interpolation for hashes is handled in strings either, so you may need to use

```
puts "#{service.to_s} : #{transactionsPerDay.to_s}"
```

Comment: Thanks Brett, but I want to have the service model itself, not the string, inside my RadioreportHelper. The Service module has the to_s implemented: def to_s
    return "id: #{id}, group: #{group}, location: #{location}, genre: #{genre}" 
  end

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of your error?  The error you listed: `TypeError: can't convert Service into String` sounds like it is coming from the line in my answer.  If you use service.to_s in your `puts` line, it will output the service as text for that puts call.  It does not change the value of the service variable, so in the next line when you do `@radio = service` you will still have the service model within your RadioreportHelper.

Comment: Thx Brett, but I still have the same error. @zetetic suggested that it was perhaps a method used by a parent class (and since ruby doesn't overwrite/overload its methods) then I should changed it.  However, when I changed it I get this: NoMethodError: undefined method `loadRadioTransaction' for RadioreportHelper:Module

Comment: What happens if you comment out the line `puts "#{service} : #{transactionsPerDay}"` and run the test case? Also can you please edit your question and add the stack trace of the exception you're getting?

Comment: Hi Brett! Just found out that the problem was that the test couldn't find the file "RadioreportHelper".  I just added the include RadioreportHelper and it is all good ;)