# Ruby: can't convert true into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Novice Ruby on Rails dev here. I recently pulled code from a remote team that was building an iPhone App, including the API for the Rails backend, but once I finished pulling the code, I get the following error in terminal when I try and start the Rails server.

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require': can't convert true into String (TypeError)
   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
   from /Users/tmylonas/Sites/getlocal/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
   from script/rails:6:in `require'
   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

And here's the application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
# If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
# If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
# Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Getlocal
class Application < Rails::Application
# Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
# Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
# -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

# Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
# :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
# config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

# Activate observers that should always be running.
# config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

# Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
# Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
# config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

# The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
# config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
# config.i18n.default_locale = :de

# Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
config.encoding = "utf-8"

# Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
config.filter_parameters += [:password]

# Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

# Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
# This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
# like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
# config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

# Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
# This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
# in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
# parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
end
end
```

And here's the gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'
gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'thin'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra', require: false
gem 'slim'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'bootbox-rails'
gem 'rails_autolink'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem "active_model_serializers", "~> 0.8.1"
gem 'google_places'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'houston', :require => true


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'underscore-rails'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :development, :test do 
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :development do 
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'sextant'
end
```

Unfortunately, the error is very nondescript. I'm not sure if this question is specific enough for SO.  If it's not, apologies, but after googling for several hours, reading threads like this one: [can't convert true into String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292538/cant-convert-true-into-string) and this one: [Ruby returns TypeError: can't convert Object into String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108193/ruby-returns-typeerror-cant-convert-object-into-string), where the code is identifiable, I thought I'd see if I could get someone to give me some more specific advice about how to diagnose and ultimately fix this issue.

Thank you much.

Comment: can u show the Gemfile ?

Comment: Hello Santosh, realize with this being downvoted that it's obviously not ideal for SO, but I went ahead and added the gemfile anyway.  Appreciate you taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the best way to answer my SO questions is to go through the process of submitting the question, sitting on it for 24 hours and then trying again.

The issue here is that the "Houston" gem, which I'm not familiar with, doesn't appear to work with Ruby 1.9.3.  Once I commented that gem out of the gemfile (thanks for Santosh for suggesting I post the gemfile because this is why I looked deeper at it!), the Rails server started right up.